# Mapkit Zoom animation

Tags: iphone, animation, mapkit, zooming, android-mapview

Does anyone know how I can imitate the zoom animation of the mapkit by setting different regions with a timer ?
I can't increment the span values as I want, because for some values, the same region is set.

I want to imitate the zoom animation by incrementing span values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't `setRegion:animated:` do the job you are looking for?

Comment: No, I want to control each frame of the animation by myself. Because I want to know all the regions the animation passed through. With this function, the region doesn't change. We have the first region and the new region.

Comment: Could you issue a series of animation requests using `setRegion:animated:` to animate each particular transition? That would likely be the smoothest animation. You could control the center/zoom yourself in a timed loop if you need absolute control.